# Enumerate all available tests in a TestNG code base

Tags: testng

I need a java function that returns a list of executable TestNG tests.  Not just classes, but methods as well.  I'd like to delegate as much of the enumeration itself to TestNG as possible.  I don't want the tests to execute, I just want to enumerate them, with the intention of executing them separately at a later time.

I've looked through the `TestNG` JavaDoc (https://javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/latest/org/testng/TestNG.html) but I don't see anything about test enumeration.  What is the preferred way to programmatically enumerate the available tests?